# Fit tensor from Keras custom loss function to another network

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, loss-function

I'm developing a custom loss function in Keras, `def loss(y_true, y_pred)`.
But I want to reuse one of there tensors (y_pred) in another neural network. I pass it to a Model object.

When I try to run my code, I get an error:
`ValueError: When feeding symbolic tensors to a model, we expect the tensors to have a static batch size. Got tensor with shape: (None, 256, 256, 3)`.

I compile the model:
`network.compile(loss=loss, optimizer='sgd')`

And run these loss function using `network.fit(x=random_array, y=np.zeros((BATCH_SIZE, imgdim[0], imgdim[1], imgdim[2])))`

How can I fit `y_pred` tensor to another network?

Comment: Not exactly clear what you are trying. Maybe put some relevant code in there.